# Angular bootstrap accordion not collapsing correctly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm working on a page which uses Accordion and Sortable together, following [this Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/TGIeeEbbvJwpJ3WRqo2z?p=preview) but while most things are behaving correctly, my accordion panels are not collapsing correctly. The header rows are moving correctly but the "body" of each accordion section is not being hidden and is showing under the following heading.

I've had a look at what's happening in the examples and it seems that when the header is clicked to collapse the panel, the panel momentarily gains a `collapsing` class which then gets replaced with a `collapse` class which hides the panel. In my case, the panels never get given the `collapse` class so the panels are still visible behind the headings below. This behaviour is seen regardless of the value of `close-others`.

Here's the relevant part of my markup:

```
<div ng-controller="myController">
    <accordion close-others="true" ui:sortable="sortableOptions" ng:model="items">
        <accordion-group ng-repeat="item in items">
            <div accordion-heading heading="{{item.name}}">
                <span class="handle btn">&#8597;</span><span>{{item.name}}</span>
            </div>
            {{item.details}}
        </accordion-group>
    </accordion>
</div>
```

And app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.sortable', 'ui.bootstrap']);

app.config(['$provide', function ($provide){
    $provide.decorator('accordionDirective', function($delegate) { 
        var directive = $delegate[0];
        directive.replace = true;
        return $delegate;
    });
  }]);

app.controller('myController', function($scope){
    $scope.items = [{name: "my item", details: "my details}, ...]
    $scope.sortableOptions = {
        handle: ' .handle',
        axis: 'y'
    };
});
```

Can anyone help, either with a solution or a workaround?

**EDIT** I've replicated this behaviour in [this Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/0pGVBWer7FurtwJatoy6?p=preview) if anyone wants to have a play.

Comment: `ng:model` instead of `ng-model`?

Comment: Well spotted, but that hasn't made a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I was using too new a version of jQuery/jQueryUI. I've downgraded to jQuery v2.1.1 and UI v1.10.0. I've also gone to v3.1.1 of the Bootstrap CSS. My final header looks like this:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.0/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.min.css" />
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

with the following script tags at the bottom of the body:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.js"></script>

<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.11.2/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-sortable/0.13.2/sortable.min.js"></script>

<script src="app.js"></script>
```

It's completely screwed my CSS as a result, but I can probably live with that!